# Bash: save ffmpeg output to a variable

Tags: bash, ffmpeg

How can i save ffmpeg file-info output to a variable?
if i put the following command into variable it's always empty, even though the command generates an output
`/usr/bin/ffmpeg/ffmpeg -i $1`

what i've tried

```
INFO=$(/usr/bin/ffmpeg/ffmpeg -i $1)

if [ -z "$INFO" ]; then
        echo "empty variable"
else
        echo "$INFO"
fi
```

Comment: what issue you are facing?

Comment: the variable is empty.

Comment: without saving into variable, can you try running the command directly within the script to make sure output is generated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try saving both STDERR and STDOUT. The following command will redirect standard error to standard output:

```
INFO=$(/usr/bin/ffmpeg/ffmpeg -i $1 2>&1)
```

By default, ffmpeg puts all its text output to STDERR, leaving STDOUT free for piping video/audio data to other applications.